# Fortigate IPSec VPN Export XML Config

Tags: vpn

I have these old config files in a proprietary .vpl format for my ipsec VPN.  Newer fortigate applications use XML.  How can I either convert this, or export a new IPSec VPN config file in XML.  I have a Fortigate 100D.  I can't find any documentation and cannot find the option, I know you can control fortigate via terminal so if that's the only way so be it, but if a GUI solution is possible in the admin panel please let me now.

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution 1 :

You can create a new XML file according to your VPN Config [here is the full and easy documentation about xml format on fortigate](http://docs.fortinet.com/d/forticlient-windows-5.0-xml)

## Solution 2 :

Fortigate provide a tool "FortiClientTools" you can use it to import your `.vpl` configuration file. and then export it to New XML Format v4.3/v5.0

Exported config files that are encrypted will likely have a filename extension of `.sconn`; unencrypted config files should be appended with `.conn`.

For newest version 5.x of FortiClient, just change the filename extension from `.sconn`; `.conn` to the newer format `.sconf`; `.conf`.

Then use 
<kbd>Menu</kbd> -> <kbd>Preferences</kbd> -> <kbd>General</kbd> -> <kbd>Restore</kbd>

## Links :

http://docs.fortinet.com/d/forticlient-windows-5.0-xml

http://kb.fortinet.com/kb/viewContent.do?externalId=FD30861

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/158278/importing-vpl-files-vpn-tunnels-on-mac

Comment: Perfect this seems to be exactly what I need, will read the docs and try out the tools, but you've pointed me in the right direction.  Thanks.  Unfortunately they want a login for the ftp to get the Tools.  Know any other way to get them?

Comment: ftp://helpscs.jp/FortiClient/win/4.0MR3Patch5/FortiClientSetup_4.3.5.0472.exe

Comment: Any idea where to get the 64 bit tools?

Comment: http://www.scsk.jp/sp/fortinet/forticlient-scsk/